# How do I work with $\sqrt{\nabla^2+k^2 }$ on $\psi$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, differentiation

How does the del operator ($\nabla$) act on the wavefunction here :

$$(\sqrt{\nabla^2+k^2})\exp(-ikz) \psi.$$

I am trying to solve an equation which has this factor. $k$ is a constant. I initially left the part alone and solved the rest of equation but didn't get the exact answer.

Comment: Without more context on your problem it's hard to tell you what is the correct way to proceed. See e.g. history of [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac.27s_coup), which deals with a similar operator initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operator is much easier to understand if you work with Fourier transform,
\begin{equation}
\psi(\vec{r})=\int d^3p e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}\tilde{\psi}(\vec{p})
\end{equation}
The multiplication on $e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}$ (with $k_x=k_y=0,k_z=k$ in your case) is equivalent to,
\begin{equation}
e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\psi(x,y,z)=\int d^3p e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}\tilde{\psi}(\vec{p}+\vec{k})
\end{equation}
The main idea is that those exponents are eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator $\Delta=\nabla^2$,
\begin{equation}
\Delta e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}=-(p^2)e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}
\end{equation}
Then your operator acts as,
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\Delta+k^2}e^{-i\vec{k}\vec{r}}\psi(\vec{r})=\int d^3p \sqrt{k^2-p^2}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}\tilde{\psi}(\vec{p}+\vec{k})
\end{equation}
Whether such representation is of any use depends on the rest of the equation of course

Comment: To be precise though, in order to prove that $\sqrt{\Delta + k^2}$ acts as a multiple of the identity onto the igenstates of $\Delta$ one should still use the Taylor expansion of the square root of an operator, which is equivalent to just using the Taylor expansion of the square root *without* using the Fourier transform.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Doesn't $\sqrt{x}$ not have a Taylor expansion? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @knzhou Sure, it does: I just wanted to emphasise that still in taking the Fourier transform doesn't hide away the process of taking the expansion of an operator.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Well, if you want to represent $\sqrt{x}=\sum_k a_k x^k$ such represenation *doesn't* exist. The square root of the operator $A$ is defined as an operator $B$ such that $B^2=A$. The way I take it is the standard one to obtain the principal square root one usually interested in.

Comment: @OON *"such represenation doesn't exist"* well, except it does, it being defined via spectral theorem. Statements like $B \mid B^2 = A$ must always be intended accompanied by their corresponding domains and so forth: your answer is correct, I just wanted to point out that it isn't different than looking at the spectral decomposition itself.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Sure you should talk about domains etc. The point is different. If you insist that such representation exists *write it*. Not even for operators, just as a representation of the number function $\sqrt{x}$. Surely you can expand as a series near $x\neq 0$ but for operators you get then a bunch of series that should individually be proven to possess the property of $B^2=A$. Your very first comment leads into something wild whereas simultaneous diagonalizability doesn't depend on the series representation at all.

Comment: @OON I agree with you, but all these wild complications are exactly solved by first representing the operators onto their spectrum and then extending to any function in the domain. You have correctly proven the action of the operator onto its basis, but the whole extension to any function in the domain is the non-trivial part. As per the number function of the square root, just take a neighbourhood where the function is analytical and calculate the expansion in there (I don't get that part of the comment).